# Reading POST request in Blazor

Tags: c#, post, blazor-server-side

Here is the problem I have.

We have a server-side Blazor web application in which we want to register new users. The users come to us from another web site. When the users subscribe to our application through this web site a POST request is sent, and the user is redirected to a page of our Blazor application. The problem is we have no clue how to then get the form data contained in the POST. We can see it using the tools in the browser, but we can't use it in my code.

We have tried creating a controller with an HTTP endpoint, but the method we have set up does not get called. My colleague and I are at a loss with what to do or what resource would be helpful and comprehensive in showing us how to set this up. Instead we keep finding little bits of information that don't lead us to a successful implementation.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: The default credentials is GUEST which may not have enough access to run the applicaiton.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs.  The HTTP response should have a status like 200 OK (or a 400,/500 error).  The controller will not work unless a good response of 200 OK is received where the body of the response has data.

Comment: Can you explain the flow a bit better? What should be happening with the POST request/payload?

Comment: @CoryPodojil 
1) User clicks on the a button on a 3rd party website. That website sends a POST request with a registration token and redirects the user to our web application DNS with the suffix "/register". On that page is a form with our registration page.
2) The Blazor app should grab the token and exchange it for a customer id  using a function provided by the 3rd party. This exchange works, as we were able to test it since we can see the token data in the browser itself. When the user fills out the registration page, we create a user with this customer id attached as an attribute.

Comment: @jdweng We do get a 200 response, it just doesn't fire off our POST function in the controller.

Comment: A controller parses an HTTP response using De-Serialization.  The response could be either JSON or XML.  And with XML the tags and namespaces have to match the response.  I don't know JSON very well but can help with XML.  If I had the XML response I can create the classes needed to for serialization.  I would capture the response with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Then create an application the parses the response from a file.  Then after getting response to work from file convert to work with an responjse over the internet.